# avoid manipulations to input from browser developer tools in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

we have login page for our application and 3 fields in login page "user name" and "password" and "login" button
Please see the below steps which explain my issue
1) I have entered a valid user name 
2) I have opened Browser Developer Tools and entered the below code

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input").item(0).value = "";
```

Then the value in "UserName" input gets cleared. 
   but the form is still valid so "login" button is enabled, and i am able to login without entering anything in "username" input.
we are using reactive forms in login page.

My issue is , if the username input is cleared then the button still enable, if i make that button disable , i can resolve my issue
or else how to make form as invalid while clearing the value of username input

Comment: Isn't there server side or explicit client side validation? How are you able to `login without entering anything`

Comment: P.S. You can't avoid 'manipulations' from dev tools.

Comment: you need to add restriction on server side too that just make sense. Client side security is only for user visualization of errors and saving user's time.

Comment: i entered valid user name and clear that from chrome console then i am able to login with user name which i have entered first time

Comment: because onchange is not triggered so it uses whatever was entered the last time change was trigger.

Comment: You can't stop the user from shooting themselves in the foot or causing "issues" with the dev tools, in much the same way that car manufacturers don't do anything to prevent car owners from adding iron shavings to the gas tank.  Yep, that's a serious issue, but one the user brings on themselves.  It doesn't arise from the normal functioning of the vehicle. It's the same here. If the user is going to go out of their way to break something, that's not an issue with your app.

Answer (score 0):

this isn't an issue with your angular application. Client side security is NOT security, it is put in place to create a consistent and sensible user experience. This is an issue with your server side security not being properly implemented as the server is where security actually resides.